# What are the different directional profiles in openrouteservice module?

Tags: python, geocoding, folium, openrouteservice

```
import folium
import openrouteservice
client=openrouteservice.Client(key='apikey')
coordinates = [77.09838732369364, 28.50036408080802]
route = client.directions(coordinates=coordinates,profile='driving-car',format='geojson')
ap_directions = folium.Map(location=[28.50036408080802,77.09838732369364],zoom_start=13,tiles="openstreetmap")
folium.GeoJson(route, name='route').add_to(map_directions)
map_directions.save("testing.html")
```

in the variable route, what other profiles can the 'profile' argument have (something like bike or walk) ??

Answer (score 0):

oh I found the profiles using the `help(openrouteservice)` method. so yeah these are the other profiles
`["driving-car", "driving-hgv", "foot-walking","foot-hiking", "cycling-regular","cycling-road","cycling-mountain","cycling-electric",]`